# User Credential - Sign In With Apple (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, swiftui, sign-in-with-apple

I am testing signing up a user with Firebase via **Sign In With Apple**. I have the basic set up which can be viewed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple).

In my `Auth.auth().sign(_:)` with credential method, I am trying to extract the `.fullName` from the `appleIDCredential` to use later to identify the user.

Here's the code in my `:didCompleteWithAuthorization` delegate method in the `func authorizationController(_:)`:

```
 let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                                      idToken: idTokenString,
                                                      rawNonce: nonce)
            
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                if let _ = authResult?.user {
                    let changeRequest = authResult?.user.createProfileChangeRequest()
                    changeRequest?.displayName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.description
                    changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in

                        if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            print("Updated display name: \(Auth.auth().currentUser!.displayName!)")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
```

I use the `.description` get-only method on the `.fullName` to get the textual representation of the returned credential, which is appropriately the full name of the user at the time of authentication.

But the final `displayName` includes the literal givenName and familyName prefixes, viz;

```
givenName: David familyName: Example
```

I tried splitting the string into an array of four elements, and filtering, but no luck.

I would like to return `David Example` from the credential, which is the user's name at the point of authentication.

**Solution**

```
    if let _ = authResult?.user {
                    let changeRequest = authResult?.user.createProfileChangeRequest()
                    
                    if let givenName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName,
                       let familyName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.familyName {

                       changeRequest?.displayName = "\(givenName) \(familyName)"
                    }
                                    
                    changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in

                        if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            print("Updated display name: \(changeRequest?.displayName ?? "")")
                        }
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the `givenName` and `familyName` separately and put them back together as `displayName` like this:

```
if let givenName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName,
   let familyName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.familyName {

   changeRequest?.displayName = "\(givenName) \(familyName)"
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you!